# AutomationAnywhere: Is there a way to view bot from botstore as processflow?

Tags: automationanywhere

I have downloaded and installed the following bot: https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/digital-oracle-accounts-payable-clerk/

I am writing a thesis about robotic process automation in audit, so I am not really interested in running the bot, but I would like to see a modelling of this process. Is there some way to review the Bot in automationAnywhere so that I

1) either see an (automatic generated) process model

2) at least see the code so that I can create this model myself?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can view this information from Automation Anywhere Client by editing the taskbot.

```
Tasks Section --> Bot Store --> DW AP Clerk - Oracle - Automation Anywhere --> My Tasks
```

Then you will find the commands and the steps used in the process.

[image: Bot Store folder]